# how to use slug to form urls

Tags: python, django, url, slug

my `models.py` file looks like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Entertainmentblog(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    img_url0 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img_alt0 =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def save(self):
        super(Entertainmentblog, self).save()
        self.slug = '%i-%s' % ( self.id, slugify(self.slug) )
        super(Entertainmentblog, self).save()
```

And my app `urls.py` file looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from entertainment import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.ListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+),(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='article'),
)
```

But this gives an error.

> Exception Value: Reverse for 'article' with arguments '(u'what-is-happening',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'entertainment/(?P[^\.]+),(?P\d+)/$']

My `view.py` file

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from entertainment.models import Entertainmentblog
class ListView(generic.ListView, slug, id):
   template_name = 'entertainment/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'

def get_queryset(self):

    return Entertainmentblog.objects.order_by('-posted')[:25]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
   model = Entertainmentblog
   template_name = 'entertainment/article.html'
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'article' with arguments '(u'what-is-happening',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'entertainment/(?P<slug>[^\\.]+),(?P<id>\\d+)/$']

Comment: This seems to be related to the view.

Comment: I'm sorry I did'nt get you.Add the view name where?

Comment: I'm sorry too, my previous comment was wrong and changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, there is serious problems with your views:

### First:

```
class ListView(generic.ListView, slug, id)
```

should be

```
class ListView(generic.ListView)
```

see [python inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

### Second:

`slug` and `id` must be class members of your view so you can redefine you view like this:

```
class ListView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'entertainment/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'
   slug = None
   id = None

def get_queryset(self):

    return Entertainmentblog.objects.order_by('-posted')[:25]
```

### Third:

Youre naming a derivate class as its parent. I don't know the implications of doing this, but surely, isn't a good practice.

### Finally:

The error you're getting is becouse the view returned by `views.DetailView.as_view()` (remember `DetailView` is your derived class) don't receives the arguments you are passing through url. Check your url, I can see in the error that is complaining about and argument `(u'what-is-happening',)` but there is no `id`. It should be something like, for example, `(u'what-is-happening', '4')`